# Set of $K$-primes over $p$ bijective with double quotient

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, quotient-spaces

Suppose $K$ is a number field with Galois closure $L$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $p$ be unramified in $L$, say $w$ is a prime of $L$ over $p$. Let the decomposition group of $w$ inside $G=Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$ be $G_w$, and let $H=Gal(L/K)$.

1. Prove that the primes of $K$ over $p$ are in bijection with the double quotient $H\backslash G/G_w$ given by $H\sigma G_w\rightarrow \sigma w\cap K$.
2. If $\sigma\rightarrow v$ in this map, show that $[K_v:\mathbb{Q}_p]=\dfrac{|H\sigma G_w|}{|H|}$.

I have no idea how to start this problem. It feels like it should be a “just do it” kind of bijection proof, but I don’t know much algebraic number theory.

Comment: Can you solve in when $L =K$?

Comment: If $L=K$ then $H$ is trivial, so it becomes a one-sided quotient. I think the decomposition group is the stabilizer of the prime, so I suppose multiplying $\sigma$ on the right by something in $G_w$ doesn't change $w$ (maybe moves it inside itself but fixes it as a whole). But I'm not sure how to calculate the degree of the extension.